# R interactive mode: is it possible to make your script stop and ask for new variable to be passed from the command line?

Tags: r, command-line, interactive, mode

I have an R script that is computing and displaying some q plots of my data in order to see which distribution do they fit. Now what i do manually is look at the plots and choose the distribution that fits better. I would like to do the same, but not in RStudio, rather from the command line:
in a nutshell, i would like that my script, after plotting and saving the plots, could stop and wait for a new indication (a keyword in this case) to be passed at the command line. I already know about commandArgs, but this should work only when launching the script, not in the middle of it.
I guess this has to do with an interactive mode?
any hint would be much appreciated,

Thanks

Alfredo

Comment: see `?readline()`

Comment: You may want to look at `svDialogs`- some options there to show options to the user that they can then select from (multiple or not). It's not commandline but works when running R via a `.bat` file, for example.